# PHP Read cookies created with setcookie()

Tags: php, cookies

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/setcookie):

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for

Meaning that a cookie created with `setcookie` will not be accessible in `$_COOKIE` until the next page load. Is there a work around for this? Is there a way to detect the cookies created with `setcookie` in PHP *without* a reload?

I can't modify the code near the `setcookie` call in the current codebase. So an solution like this won't work:

```
setcookie('test', 'my test value');
$_COOKIE['test'] = 'my test value';
```

Comment: There is no way as far as I can see, short of overriding `setcookie()` as Marc B shows, but that is a nasty business.

Comment: Kind of the same idea as Marc B's answer, but this one requires APD as well... http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php  I think your best bet is to search and replace all functions of setcookie() to set_cookie() and you make your own set_cookie() that does both instances,  Which I know you said you can't do but its the best solution.  --- On a side idea, maybe you can do a AJAX/XmlHttpRequest to a php script that returns whatever value you need from the cookie and changes the page with whatever data you need after its rendered =]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The _COOKIES superglobal is created as part of the script's initialization, and then is left alone by PHP. As such, any cookies you create later in the script will not magically appear in the array, as they were not present at initialization time.

You can override the built-in setcookie functionality with [`runkit_function_redefine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php), but if you're not very careful, you can open yourself up to a world of hurt.

Comment: Didn't actually end up implementing this function - instead, hacked the changes into the code that I wasn't supposed to hack. Accepted because it appears to be the only way to make this happen.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a session instead and it will be available immediately and will limit the amount of data stored in the cookie as it will just store the session id. You can use complex data too.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['my_var'] = 'something';
$_SESSION['another_var'] = array(1, 2, 3);

$my_var = $_SESSION['my_var'];
echo $my_var;
?>
```

Comment: His problem is he has setcookie() calls in code he can't modify, this is an obvious solution but doesn't meet his credentials.

Comment: But it is a great suggestion, a suggestion that the asker should really look for since what he ask cannot be done.

Comment: Persistence between requests is not the issue. If I could control the write then storing the data in any global, super-global or class property would work.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could make a landing page and redirect if the cookie is not set forcing the cookie to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

A trick to refresh the cookie content without reload all the page is doing an Ajax request, because its reply HTTP header will update the cookie. For example:

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php setcookie('test', 'my test value', 0, '/'); ?>

<a href="#" id="see-cookie">See the cookie content updated</a>
```

**Ajax request with JQuery**

```
$("#see-cookie").click( function() {

    $.ajax({

        url: "/ajax/ajax_test.php",
        success: function(html){

            alert(html);

        }

    });

});
```

**PHP that receives the Ajax request**

```
$new_cookie = 'Updated at ' . date('H:i:s') . ' - ' . $_COOKIE['test'];

setcookie('test', $new_cookie, 0, '/');

echo $new_cookie;
```