# Cookie Not Available Sitewide

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm having two issues with setting and retrieving cookies.

1. Cookie gets loaded but can't be called until page is refreshed. Meaning that the cookie shows up in developer tools but not when trying to use its value on the page. The value does seem available to use on page after refreshing.
2. Cookie is not available across entire domain and subdirectories. For example, if the user enters at http://example.com/sub/ the goes to http://example.com/, the cookie gets destroyed.

Here's my code:

```
$ad_source = $_GET['source'];
$date_of_expiry = time() + (86400 * 7);
setcookie('ad_source',$ad_source,$date_of_expiry,'/');

if ( $_COOKIE['ad_source'] == 'adwords_campaign_01' ) {
    echo '... do something';
} elseif ( $_COOKIE['ad_source'] == 'adwords_campaign_02' ) {
    echo '... do something else';
}
```

I'm trying to to show different information throughout entire site by determining what adwords campaign the user clicked in on.

I don't usually use cookies and prefer to set a session, but in this case I want be able to track the source for a longer amount of time.

Comment: For the first point, at the begining of your script, try to put ini_set('display_errors', false); error_reporting(0), this is from the doc page where it says (cookies must be sent before any output from your script).
For the second point, try to use the fifth parameter, also mentioned in the doc page of the function.

Comment: Error reporting showed nothing.I also tried adding the domain as the fifth parameter, but it made no difference. The same results occurred.

Comment: I solved issue 2 by first checking for the checking for $ad_source before setting the cookie. if ( $ad_source ) { setcookie('ad_source',$ad_source,$date_of_expiry,'/');}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working as expected now. A little more insightful information into cookies at this post helped a lot.

[PHP cookie set in second refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085821/php-cookie-set-in-second-refresh-page)

1. Redirect user to page after cookie is set. Second request from browser sends cookie, server returns info relative to its value.
2. Check to see if $ad_source is set before creating cookie.

The updated code:

```
$ad_source = $_GET['source'];
$date_of_expiry = time() + (86400 * 7);

if ( $ad_source ) {

  setcookie('ad_source',$ad_source,$date_of_expiry,'/','example.com');

  if ( $_COOKIE['ad_source'] == 'adwords_campaign_01' ) {
    header( 'Location: http://example.com/' );
    echo '... do something';
  } elseif ( $_COOKIE['ad_source'] == 'adwords_campaign_02' ) {
    header( 'Location: http://example.com/' );
    echo '... do something else';
  }

}
```