# PHP Cookie and browser refresh confusion

Tags: php

I have this code here and I noticed when I changed the value to something else. I have to refresh the page not once but twice in order to see the new value.

Is this related to HTTP headers and super globals? or something why do I have to refresh twice to see the new value why is not one refresh? I've tried reading similar questions on other threads but still not clear on this manner as far why? and what's doing. Can someone give me a clear explanation, thank you.

```
<?php
$name = "test";
$value = "hello";
$expire = time() + (60*60*24*7); 
setcookie($name, $value, $expire);    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
$test = isset($_COOKIE["test"]) ? $_COOKIE["test"] : ""; 
echo $test;
?>
</body>
```

so If I change the value to say 500 then I have to refresh twice to see the new value on the page.

Comment: After setting cookies using `setcookie()`, you can get cookies using `$_COOKIE[]` **only on next time page load**, In same script execution you can't to set and get cookies (Its possible in `$_SESSION[]`)

Comment: It's stateless so u won't be able to achieve in the manner you want, you could use temporary session for this one.

Comment: Check your network tab and see the cookies that are being shipped with the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085896/2243372 .

Try to refresh your page programmatically. Example:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) {
    echo 'COOKIE = ', $_COOKIE['test'];
} else {
    setcookie('test', 'my-cookie-value', strtotime('+1 day'));
    if ( ! isset($_GET['setcookie'])) {
        header('Refresh: 0; url=?setcookie=done');
    } else {
        echo 'Your browser does not accept cookies!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Does php has [session key](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) already? Try [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). Sessions in php works without cookies (if disabled).