# Display a php cookie in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I have set a cookie using php.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
include_once 'php/config.php';
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($_POST['username']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if($row==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        setcookie('username', $username, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGGEDIN...";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='index.html'},2000);</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
            echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='index.html'},2000);</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

I want display the 'username' cookie in html like Hi ""
.
Please Help.

Tried this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name)
  {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet you have tried till now.

Comment: what is problem in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span id="myId"><span>
<script>
document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML=listCookies()
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
        aString += i + ' ' + theCookies[i-1] + "\n";
}
    return aString;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried the first code. It's showing something like:

Comment: 1 PHPSESSID=2564e2cad3dbbc17223e4ae4be8df149 2 username=jatinluthra14

Comment: I want only username

Comment: you can check,http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

Comment: Not able to figure it out. Yours worked earlier. Please tell how to implement the second one so I only receive username.

Comment: It isn't giving any output.

Comment: Hi I modified it so it shows only last cookie. Can't it be done to show only specific cookie

Comment: Please tell The solution.

Comment: sorry,I am go for lunch

Comment: It's okay, Thanks.Just modified it

Comment: where i need to modify

Comment: Your code isn't working. The 2nd isn't working at all. 1st one was correct but was giving both so I modified to show only username one using IndexOf

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo $_COOKIE['username'];` instead of `echo $_SESSION['username'];`. It will echo out of the second reload of the page. ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085821/php-cookie-set-in-second-refresh-page))

Comment: In your file you just need to echo out. For eg <?=$_COOKIE['username']?>. Here is the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php