# Need to add and read values into cookie before page loads because page items need to be shown as per the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cookies, pageload

I have a requirement where I need to call a service on page load and it will return some data, using that data I need to add into browser cookies and based on the value from cookie need to show the page content on page load itself.

Actually I'm using

`$(document).ready(function(){ )}`

function but I can only read the data on my second load of my page but not on my first load.

Redirect the user to the page after the cookie value set is not a good practice of implementation and also not provide good user experience

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cookie set in second refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085821/php-cookie-set-in-second-refresh-page)

Comment: This is not a valid approach for this, because I don't want to redirect the user to the same page once after the data is stored in cookie. As it is not a valid or good user experience.

Answer (score -3):

Can you have a look into the following link,
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I'm sorry but just link without any explanation is not real response.